# working with editable with vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, contenteditable

I have a table that look like [image: this]:

here i can define how many rows and columns i want on my table and the table get updated as i want, at here everything fine, the next step i need is to change the content of each cell and bind it to an array, i really don't know how to accomplish this, seems like contenteditable has some issues with v-model.

Another problem is that i don't know how to pass the data to my data object, should i pass it as a matrix? a array? i need to know each input for the specific row and columns, any help?

**here is what i did so far:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form class="form-horizontal">
      <h2 class="text-center"> Table </h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <button @click="changeView('appTableStyle')" type="button" class="form-control btn btn-xs btn-warning">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>&nbsp;
          </button>
        </div>
        <label for="rows" class="control-label col-md-1">style:</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <select class="form-control" v-model="table.tableStyle">
            <option v-for="(item,key) in tableStyles" :value="item.Id">
              {{ item.style }}
            </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rows" class="control-label col-md-2">rows:</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="number" min="1" v-model="table.rows" class="form-control" id="rows">
        </div>
        <label for="columns" class="control-label col-md-1">columns:</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="number" min="1" v-model="table.cols" class="form-control" id="cols">
        </div>
        <label for="columns" class="control-label col-md-2">How Many?:</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="number" min="1" v-model="insert" class="form-control" id="cols">
        </div>
      </div>
      <table class="table table-responsive" style="background-color:lightGray">
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(row,idx2) in tableRows">
            <td v-model="table.colsArr[idx]" :key="" class="table-success" v-for="(col,idx) in tableCols" contenteditable="true">{{idx}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-9">
          <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" @click.prevent="addTable" class="btn btn-success margin-above2 btn-block">Add Table</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>


<script>

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      table: {
        rows: 1,
        cols: 1,
        key: 'Table',
        tableStyle: 1,
        colsArr: []
      },
      insert: 1
    }
  },
  methods: {

    },
    changeView: function (view) {
      this.$store.commit('changeCurrentView', view)
    }
  },

  computed: {
    tableStyles () {
      return this.$store.getters.getTableStyles
    },
    tableRows () {
      return parseInt(this.table.rows)
    },
    tableCols () {
      return parseInt(this.table.cols)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```